# creating initial population for genetic algorithm

Tags: python, binary, genetic-algorithm

I need to create the initial population to solve this equation z = x⁵ - 10x³ + 30x - y² + 21y using genetic algorithm. The population must be binary and need to follow this rules:

X and Y range: [-2.5, 2.5]

The first bit represents the signal (0 or 1)

The second and third bit represents the integer part, values from 0 to 2 (00, 01, 10)

The rest should represents the float part, values from 0 to 5000.

```
def pop(pop_size):

pop = []
for i in range(pop_size):
    for j in range(2):
        signal = bin(np.random.randint(0, 2))[2:]
        integer = bin(np.random.randint(0, 3))[2:]
        float = bin(np.random.randint(0, 5001))[2:].zfill(13)
        binary = [signal, integer, float]
        binary = [''.join(binary)]
        pop.append(binary)

return pop
```

My output right now looks like this: `[['1110001000110000'], ['1100010010011000'], ['11000100010001010'], ['0100011000000010'], ['0100010111100001'], ['01000111001101110']]`

But I need it to look like this: `[['1110001000110000', '1100010010011000'], ['11000100010001010', '0100011000000010'], ['0100010111100001', '01000111001101110']]` **because each pair represents the value for X and Y**.

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: It looks like you are already generating valid bit strings.  So the question is how to group existing values into pairs?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi basically yes, but I still wanna make sure if this works properly, because I never used binary. When I get to the elitism, selection, crossover and mutation I'm screwed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```py
def pop(pop_size)
    rlt = []
    for i in range(pop_size):
        rlt.append([None,None])
        for j in range(2):
            signal = bin(np.random.randint(0, 2))[2:]
            integer = bin(np.random.randint(0, 3))[2:]
            floats = bin(np.random.randint(0, 5001))[2:].zfill(13)
            rlt[-1][j] = signal+integer+floats
    return rlt
```

Demo

```
>>> pop(3)
[['0100111010000110', '000110111010111'], ['100101100010010', '010010000101100'], ['0100011000011010', '0100111100001011']]
```